# how to delete "google sign in account" for development purpose - actions on google

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm working with actions on google and dialogflow, and recently they proposed google signin to make account linking fast without writing own oauth server.

Today I implemented their google signin in my dialogflow app it is working quite fine but unfortunately I am unable to delete that account to check all development aspects, I tried my other google accounts and my friends account but soon ended up out of accounts

Un other methods when i enable and disable testing it forget about linking but in google signin it is tightly stick with the account, and i have tried almost everything i can try like restarting my phone and clearing cache of chrome browser but it looks like it is saving account somewhere in cloud.

What i need to do is, when i sign in first time it ask for name permission, i need that screen again and again for testing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google calls this Removing a Website or App that has access to your account. It is done using the [myaccount.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com) console.

If you want to do this using Android, the easiest way is to:

1. Open your device's Settings app Settings app and then Google and then Google Account.
2. At the top, tap Security.
3. Under "Signing in to other sites," tap Signing in with Google.
4. Tap the name of your project.
5. Choose Remove access.

Through the web, you can go to [Apps With Access to your Accounts](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions):

1. Scroll down to the "Signing in with Google" section
2. Locate your project.
3. Select it, and choose "Remove access"

[image]

The name that is shown should be the name you've given to your project as part of the OAuth screen. If you haven't set that up (and if you're just playing around, you probably haven't), it will use the Project ID for your project. You can find this on the Cloud Console home screen attached to the same project name that you used in Dialogflow and the Action Console.

[image]

While you're in there, you will probably want to configure the OAuth screen to have a name for the app as it will be visible to users on the OAuth screen. From the menu, select "APIs & Services" and then "Credentials"

[image]

Select the "OAuth consent screen" tab, and fill in the "Application name".

[image]

This name should then be in the list of applications you have installed, and can remove.

Comment: hmmm, I remember i visit that page earlier but i didt realize i need to search project id, instead i deleted dialogflow access LoLz, I will try it out now

Comment: I have a lot of project there with numbers like this, how do i locate the correct one? everywhere dialogflow actions on google and google console my project is refered by name IVOW not number

Comment: Removing access from https://myaccount.google.com/permissions and using http://gala-demo.appspot.com should be enough :)